# why cte recursive returns just the first row?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Please someone take a look at this CTE and tell me what's wrong with it? It just returns the first row (anchor).

**EDIT:**
This one works at it should, but I wonder what's wrong with the tables and data!!!

```
Create table Menus (MenuID uniqueidentifier primary key, MenuName nvarchar(100))
Create table MenuItems (MenuItemID uniqueidentifier primary key, PID uniqueidentifier null, MenuID uniqueidentifier not null, MenuItemName nvarchar(100) not null)

insert into Menus values ('3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67', 'Main')

insert into MenuItems values ('D3B92D1B-7AFA-4E11-AF01-9F6A00B1B2A9', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67', 'Books')
insert into MenuItems values ('70575C44-1EF8-497F-B7B8-A18300F645D7', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67', 'CDs')
insert into MenuItems values ('2D6ED5B3-4C6A-4907-8571-A196009727D7', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67', 'DVDs')
insert into MenuItems values ('3A1096E7-5FD2-4F77-9729-A19600973BDF', '2D6ED5B3-4C6A-4907-8571-A196009727D7', '3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67', 'Movies')
insert into MenuItems values ('5C2AC1F8-DEE0-448B-B538-A19600F0839B', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67', 'Cassetes')
GO

declare @MenuID uniqueidentifier
set @MenuID = '3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67'
;WITH 
cte (MenuItemID, PID, Lvl) 
AS 
    (
    select MenuID as MenuItemID, cast(null as uniqueidentifier) as PID, 1
        from Menus where MenuID = @MenuID
    union all
    select MenuItems.MenuItemID
            , PID = case MenuItems.pid when '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' then @MenuID else MenuItems.pid end
            , cte.Lvl + 1 
        from MenuItems
            inner join cte on cte.MenuItemID = MenuItems.PID
        where MenuItems.MenuID = @MenuID
    )
select * from cte
```

**EDIT:
The result should be like this:**

```
3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67    NULL    1
D3B92D1B-7AFA-4E11-AF01-9F6A00B1B2A9    3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67    2
70575C44-1EF8-497F-B7B8-A18300F645D7    3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67    2
2D6ED5B3-4C6A-4907-8571-A196009727D7    3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67    2
5C2AC1F8-DEE0-448B-B538-A19600F0839B    3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67    2
3A1096E7-5FD2-4F77-9729-A19600973BDF    2D6ED5B3-4C6A-4907-8571-A196009727D7    3
```

Thanks in advance!

Kardo

Comment: This looks suspicious, if MenuID is the PK: `and  MenuItems.MenuID = @MenuID`

Comment: it's so to select an specific row. The problem is with the rest I guess, but not sure really.

Comment: So show sample data and desired results, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: I just updated my question. The sample tables works fine, but the real one returns just the first row!

Comment: So you're saying the sample data you added to the question won't let us reproduce your error? If they do, can you tell us what you ***expect*** to see.

Comment: yes, and the real data are too complicated to show here :(

Comment: Well if we can't show us how to break it, we can't understand how it's broken, so I'm not sure what you expect anyone here to do for you.

Comment: I got it. The problem is with the "select case statement". There I replace the MenuItemIDs = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' with @MenuItemID, but in the JOIN statement (inner join cte on cte.MenuItemID = MenuItems.PID) I compare them with the non-replaced data. But I wonder how to fix the issue?!

Comment: No idea. Word problems are not my specialty, sorry.

Comment: I updated my question again. Now It's exactly the problem I have in real. Would you take a look please?

Comment: For the Nth time, please tell us what you *expect* the result to be!

Comment: Sorry for late-understanding :| I put the expected result in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you need to replace `inner join cte on cte.MenuItemID = MenuItems.PID` with `inner join cte on cte.MenuItemID = MenuItems.MenuID`

Comment: Hey guys, many thanks for your help. I fixed the issue as I put it in the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I fixed my problem using a sub-query:

```
declare @MenuID uniqueidentifier
set @MenuID = '3AB564A7-1D2C-4C43-91E3-A191016CBE67'
;WITH 
cte (MenuItemID, PID, Lvl) 
AS 
    (
    select MenuID as MenuItemID, cast(null as uniqueidentifier) as PID, 1
        from Menus where MenuID = @MenuID
    union all 
    select mi.MenuItemID, mi.PID, cte.Lvl + 1  from (select MenuItems.MenuItemID
            , PID = case MenuItems.pid when '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' then @MenuID else MenuItems.pid end
        from MenuItems
        where MenuItems.MenuID = @MenuID) as mi
            inner join cte on cte.MenuItemID = mi.PID
    )
select * from cte
```

THANKS A LOT for the guys tried to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems in

```
 inner join cte on cte.MenuItemID = MenuItems.PID
```

Because MenuItemID and PID will not match.

Provide the table structure and sample data for further analysis and to simulate the problem actually.

Comment: I just updated my question. The sample tables works fine, but the real one returns just the first row!